# Slurm action at job termination or failure

Tags: slurm, termination

I would like the `slurm` workload manager to do some action like `touch stopped.txt` at job termination either due to time out or failure. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the job has terminated, there is no way for regular users to perform further actions. (Admins can use `strigger` or setup epilog scripts)

For termination due to time out, the typical course of action is to setup a Bash ["trap"](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html) to catch a signal and [request Slurm to send that signal](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OPT_signal) a few minutes before the job is killed.

For termination due to failure, you can [test the return code](https://linuxhint.com/bash-exit-code-of-last-command/) of your main program inside the submission script and act accordingly.

Another option, which could be seen as overkill, but is easier to implement, is to submit a "monitoring" job, [dependent](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OPT_dependency) on the job after which some action must be taken, and have that job create the `stopped.txt` file based on the [state of the job in the accounting](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacct.html).